# Trying to run go get -u getting error: package XXX: unrecognized import path "_/XXX" (import path does not begin with hostname)

Tags: go

I'm working in Windows.

Full Error: package */C*/Go_Projects: unrecognized import path "*/C*/Go_Projects" (import path does not begin with hostname)

`GOPATH=C:\Go_Projects
GOROOT=C:\Go
path=path;C:\Go_Projects\bin`

Go_Projects contains: bin, src, pkg and some .bat files but that's it.

I've tried changing GOROOT/GOPATH to:

`GOPATH=\\Go_Projects
GOROOT=C:\Go\bin, \\Go\bin, \\Go`

I'm not sure how to fix this, I keep getting errors and my GOPATH is never set properly.

Comment: Don't set GOROOT, set GOPATH with the full path, and then show what you are doing to get the error above.

Comment: by full path do you mean \bin?

I've tried removing GOROOT but keeping everything else, still same error

Comment: EDIT: please post the full command you are trying to execute (go get -u WHAT GOES HERE?)

Comment: just running go get -u, not trying to build or anything

Comment: Yeah, sorry, hadn't noticed the title. Please post the full command.

Comment: If `Go_Projects` has `bin`, `pkg` and `src` directories, you've gotten something to install at some point. GOPATH should be a fully qualified path.

Answer (score 1):

I reproduced the error by trying go get -u without specifying the path. Go get -u fetches a remote repository and builds it, so you should pass a path, like this:

```
go get -u github.com/gorilla/mux
```

If you don't specify a path, it will consider the path to be the current working dir, which is probably not what you want to do.

And GOPATH is not a valid path for a go get, you could do it from a child directory though, but usually you pass the whole path as I mentioned above.